# How to install an unsafe APK after allowing Play Protect to block it?

Tags: side-loading, play-protect

I was just wondering, when installing an APK from an unknown source and you click OK to allow **Play Protect** to block it, is there a way of installing that app without fully disabling **Play Protect**?

When trying to install the same app after allowing the block, it shows *App not installed*.

[image: IMG:] 
[image: IMG:]

Comment: Did you try "Install anyway (unsafe)"?

Comment: So my question is how do you install it when you dont click that

Comment: You can try sideloading via adb.